# use of history back button dettection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-history

I'm making jquery mobile app and have one problem.
I have three pages:

- main page with category clicks
- page with itemlist and category filter.
- page with item details

when I click category on main page I go to second page with modified select button and filtered list. after clicking item and using history button everything is ok - right category is selected. 
Problem is when I want to on a second page change category. After clicking item and going back in history I go back to first category not previously changed one.
Is there a way to detect wheather back button was used??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // do something
    localStorage.back=1;
  }
});
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache a page using:

```
 <div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true">
```

or intercept the back button action with:

```
 jQuery.mobile.navigate( url [, data ] )
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
window.history.go(-2);
```